# How to prevent a column to grow width and push other column in Word?

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, report, reportviewer

I've tried this for 2 hours with no success.

I have a report viewer with a table with some columns. The problem is that depending on the lenght of a "Description", the column gets bigger than Microsoft Word margin, so it pushes the next column, so my another column disappears.

I already set CanGrow = true to everything, I also mixed with False value, and mixed with CanShrink.

How can I freeze the column Width?

The problem only occurs on Word. I also noticed that if I click on the table in the word document, and select > Auto Adjust > Fixed Width Column, it fits well. but I can't ask the user to do it manually :P
.[image]

In this picture, the "COL E" pushes the next column because there are other row way down with a huge description.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your second paragraph as a details column with following parameters:

- CanGrow - True
- CanShrink - False

. The results are below:

[image]

If you set *CanGrow* to False then Details column will be cut off ending "I have a report".

Comment: But try a text without space like: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"